# Convenient way to delete element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jsx

I have a dynamically populated array `links` which is rendered as a list. List items have a button which have to delete whole item.

```
<ol>
    {links.map(function (element, index) {
        return (
            <li key={index}>
                <Link href={element}>{element}</Link>
                <Button onClick={ (event) => {} }>X</Button>
            </li>
        )
    })}
</ol>
```

The obvious solution it is to remove current index from `links` array. However `event` cannot pass any useful indication of what index the `li` has. Going for `event.target.parentNode.parentNode.children.indexOf(event.target.parentNode)` chain only to get its index is not the best solution. How can it be processed easier?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding custom function inside `onClick` function and passing `index` into it.

```
function handleDelete(index) {
    console.log(index) // this is the index of the li's correspondent item in links
    const arr = [...links]
    arr.splice(index, 1) // remove the element
}
<ol>
    {links.map(function (element, index) {
        return (
            <li key={index}>
                <Link href={element}>{element}</Link>
                <Button onClick={ (event) => { handleDelete(index) } }>X</Button>
            </li>
        )
    })}
</ol>
```